# Detect member or non-member function context ("this" exists or not)

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a macro. Is there a way to detect if it's used in member or non-member function context? I.e. whether `this` pointer exists or not?
I tried to use `constexpr if` but could not get rid of error `invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function`:

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

#define macro(a, b, c) \
  do { \
    const char* class_name; \
    if constexpr (std::is_class<decltype(*this)>::value) \
      class_name = typeid(*this).name(); \
    else \
      class_name = ""; \
  } while (0)

struct foo {
  void member () {
    macro(1, 2, 3);
  }
};

void non_member() {
  macro(4, 5, 6);
}
```

I would be grateful to see how this problem is solved using C++14 (since I'm bound to it) and C++20.

Comment: FWIW, `if constexpr` only works in template code.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. *Why* do you want to write a macro that can be invoked in member- and non-member functions, and do different things in each? (I'll assume that you have a good reason for using a macro in the first place.)

Comment: *"if constexpr only works in template code"* And even then, both branches must be theoretically valid for *some* template arguments. (So you can't wrap all of that in a template lambda.) And the condition being invalid won't be interpreted as `false`, you'll get an error.

Comment: Initially I used this macro to facilitate debugging (quick and easy temporary logging). It is a macro because I used `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__`. Then used it in non-member function. Now I'm curious how can this be solved.

Comment: I've just tried to use `constexpr if` in non-template function - no problem.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat For logging you could use the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro on GCC/Clang and `__FUNCSIG__` on MSVC.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Failing of constexpr if in case of SFINAE only works in templated code. Simply checking results of compile time constants works also in non templated code as I know. In the case of the macro accessing this in non templated code will fail but did not make the constexpr to false which results in the access error of this.

Comment: @Klaus It "works", but it wont discard the non-used path since it is not dependent.  `if constexpr` only discards non-taken dependent branches.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, the check is done like in a run time if and not like an #if within a template. Thats right and also the answer I believe :-)

Answer (score 1):

From [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

> If a constexpr if statement appears inside a templated entity, and if condition is not value-dependent after instantiation, the discarded statement is not instantiated when the enclosing template is instantiated .

vs

> Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if constexpr is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive:

In your case, you call the macro and `constexpr if` inside it within a non templated function. So the access of the non existing `this` is ill formed.

In addition, as your `constexpr if` is not accessing template parms, SFINAE did not happen and even this will also let the expression inside the if clause fail.